# Google Cloud - Save Email Attachments (invoices) then Delete

Tags: php, google-drive-api, gmail, google-oauth, imap

I've coded the script below. This code connects to a Gmail account, searches for emails with attachments, and saves the attachments to Google Drive. It also deletes the emails from the Gmail account.

But anytime I run it:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login Required", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Login Required" } }

I tried several changes. Nothing works. Even ChatGPT cannot find the fix/error.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Include the autoload file
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Set your OAuth 2.0 Client IDs
$client_id = '123456789012-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_secret = 'ABC-XYZ_123';

// Set your redirect URI
$redirect_uri = 'https://example.com/invoices';

// Create a new Google_Client object
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

// Set the scopes for the API services you want to use
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

// Authorize the client
$client->authorize();

// Create a new Google_Service_Drive object
$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Connect to Gmail
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$username = 'email@gmail.com';
$password = 'password';

// Connect to Gmail
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

// Get all emails from inbox
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

// If emails are returned
if($emails) {
    
    // Sort emails by date
    rsort($emails);
    
    // Loop through emails
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        
        // Get the full header of the email
        $header = imap_fetchheader($inbox, $email_number);

        // Parse the header into an object
        $header_obj = imap_rfc822_parse_headers($header);

        // Get the original sender's name
        $sender_name = $header_obj->from[0]->personal;

        // Get the date the email was sent
        $date_sent = strtotime($header_obj->date);
        $formatted_date_sent = date("Y-m-d", $date_sent);

        // Get the attachments
        $attachments = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$email_number);
        
        // If attachments are found
        if(isset($attachments->parts) && count($attachments->parts)) {
            
            // Loop through attachments
            for($i = 0; $i < count($attachments->parts); $i++) {
                
                // Check if the attachment is an object
                if (is_object($attachments->parts[$i])) {
                    // Get the attachment data
                    $attachment_data = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,$i+1);

                    // Decode the attachment data
                    $attachment_data = base64_decode($attachment_data);

                    // Create the filename
                    $filename = $formatted_date_sent . ' ' . $sender_name;
                    
                    // Save the attachment to Google Drive
                    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
                    $file->setName($filename);
                    $file->setDescription('Invoice attachment');
                    $file->setMimeType('application/pdf');
                    $file->setParents(array('1nkfPyEvFYR_DGUGJDiy8WLx_ANUNsAdW'));
                    $createdFile = $driveService->files->create($file, array(
                        'data' => $attachment_data,
                        'mimeType' => 'application/pdf',
                        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
    
    // Delete the email
    imap_delete($inbox,$email_number);
    }
}

// Close the connection
imap_close($inbox);

?>
```

Comment: Which call is causing the error? you have added to code that authorize $driveService

Comment: When I run the page from my web browser. The file is saved under index3.php in one of my sub-folders.

Comment: Yes but where are you requesting authorization of the user? $driveService needs to be authorized.  [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you are simply creating a drive service object but not acutally calling any authorization on it.

```
// Create a new Google_Service_Drive object
$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
```

You need to request consent of the user who's drive account you want to write to.  With out that your service object is not authorized and you will get a `"Login Required"` error messages becouse your not logged in.

```
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {
        
        $client = buildClient();
        
        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }
        
        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            
            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 
            
            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Code ripped from [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

Comment: Oh thanks I didn't know that. So I should just copy/paste that snippet of code before line "$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);" right?

Comment: Actually i think you should read though all of the Oauth2Authentication.php I linked and understand it.  Its to much code to link here.   Technically speaking if you are only writing to a single drive account you should consider using a service account instead it would save you some trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I correctly implement it since now I get this Google Sign-in pop-up that asks for authorization. Although no file is saved to my Google Drive after completion, neither is the email deleted... Not sure what's blocking the script to fully do his work.

Comment: do a files.list to see if you can see the file,  or check the response body to ensure  you have a file id for the newly created file